# jQuery DataTable: Callback function(fnUpdate, fnCreatedCell, etc) doesn't work if mData is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I create `dataGrid using jQuery DataTable`. However, I found problem to update cell when value of mData is null like code below:

```
var oTable = $("table#table_lookup").dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aaData": data,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
            "sTitle": "No.", 
            "mData": null,
            "aTargets": [0], 
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).text((iRow + 1));
            }],
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
});
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

when [mData](http://datatables.net/ref#mData) is null, you need to specify [sDefaultContent](http://datatables.net/ref#sDefaultContent) option which can be set a empty string `""`, like:

```
var oTable = $("table#table_lookup").dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aaData": data,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ 
            "sTitle": "No.", 
            "mData": null,
            "sDefaultContent": "", //add this
            "aTargets": [0], 
            "bSortable": false,
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                $(nTd).text((iRow + 1));
            }],
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
});
```